# Matlab GUI: Reading from Serial port and showing in different listboxes at the same time

Tags: matlab, user-interface, serial-port

I am working with serial port and multiple list boxes to read data in serial port. The listboxes are used to read specific data (suppose the data is coming from 3 different sources, so I have 3 listboxes).

Now the problem:

I want to read all the data separately and continuously. I mean, when I am clicking one listbox (e.g. listbox#2) after reading listbox#1's data, the listbox#1 automatically stops, so again I need to click listbox#1 to read the data for listbox#1. But I want to get the data continuously in all the listboxes without clicking (clicking for first time to initializing) every time. How can I achieve this? I have tried other ways but not working.

Additional comment: It worked as per the below comments.

Sample code [Edited and OpeningFcn has been added]:

```
function main_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
 handles.output = hObject;
 handles.timer   = timer(...
 'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', ...       % Run timer repeatedly
 'Period', 1, ...                        % Initial period is 1 sec.
 'TimerFcn', {@listbox1_Callback, handles});
 guidata(hObject, handles);

function listbox1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
     %serConn is the connection to COM port
     out = fscanf(handles.serConn);
     string = 'degrees1';
     t=1;
     while(t < 15)
     if strncmp(out,string,8)
     rxtext = out(14:15);
     currList = get(handles.listbox, 'String');
     set(handles.listbox,'String',...
       [currList ;  [temp]]);
     end
     pause(5);
     t = t+1;
     end
```

Comment: Is this where a `timer` might be useful?

Comment: @GeoffHayes, Thanks for your comment. I am not very much familiar with timer function, but tried the above one [the edited code] and it shows following error: 
Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer 'timer-1'. Would you help me in correcting the error please? I have tried to remove/replace the timer arguments as well as listbox1 arguments but that does not change the error message.

Comment: Define a different function for your `TimerFcn` to avoid conflict with the user calling the `listbox1_Callback` whilst playing with the listbox, and because the input parameters to the `TimerFcn` will not be 'hObject' and 'eventData' but related to the timer object.  Define something like `function [] = timerCallback(varargin)`.  Note that passing in `handles` will only pass that copy at time of when the timer was instantiated, so will not have the `serConn` field which may be the reason of the error.  Put a breakpoint in your timer callback and check for the error.

Comment: Yes after separating the two functions, it is working. Thank you!